# How remove a certain node in text?

Tags: xpath, xidel

https://www.iana.org/domains/arpa

I can get following output using the xpath '//table[@id="arpa-table"]/tbody/tr/join((td[1], normalize-space(td[2])), x:cps(9))' with xidel. But I want to put things like `RFC 3172` in a 3rd column and `/go/rfc3172` in a forth column. Does anybody let me know how you do it?

```
arpa▸   Reserved exclusively to support operationally-critical infrastructural identifier spaces as advised by the Internet Architecture Board RFC 3172¬
as112.arpa▸ For sinking DNS traffic for reverse IP address lookups and other applications RFC 7535¬
e164.arpa▸  For mapping E.164 numbers to Internet URIs RFC 6116¬
home.arpa▸  For non-unique use in residential home networks RFC 8375¬
in-addr-servers.arpa▸   For hosting authoritative name servers for the in-addr.arpa domain RFC 5855¬
in-addr.arpa▸   For mapping IPv4 addresses to Internet domain names RFC 1035¬
ip6-servers.arpa▸   For hosting authoritative name servers for the ip6.arpa domain RFC 5855¬
ip6.arpa▸   For mapping IPv6 addresses to Internet domain names RFC 3152¬
ipv4only.arpa▸  For detecting the presence of DNS64 and for learning the IPv6 prefix used for protocol translation RFC 7050¬
iris.arpa▸  For locating Internet Registry Information Services RFC 4698¬
uri.arpa▸   For resolving Uniform Resource Identifiers according to the Dynamic Delegation Discovery System RFC 3405 RFC 8958¬
urn.arpa▸   For resolving Uniform Resource Names according to the Dynamic Delegation Discovery System RFC 3405¬
```

The first row should be something like

```
arpa▸   Reserved exclusively to support operationally-critical infrastructural identifier spaces as advised by the Internet Architecture Board▸ RFC 3172¬
```

Comment: You mean `//table[@id="arpa-table"]/tbody/tr/join((td[1],normalize-space(td[2]/text()),td[2]/span/a,td[2]/span/a/@href),x:cps(9))` ?

Comment: Not exactly. Things like RFC 3172 should be removed from the 2nd column.

Comment: The 2nd item (`normalize-space(td[2]/text())`) strings don't contain _"RFC [...]"_. Could you otherwise please explain what output you're exactly looking for?

Comment: Reino's output looks to me like exactly what you are asking for. If indeed it is, could you please [edit] to show in more detail what your expected output should look like? Gist: https://gist.github.com/tripleee/be3249802718d6c52d37ba2089967a94

Comment: @Reino You last edit should work. How does text() only get the text before RFC.... Why without it, it would include RFC ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `xidel` prints the node/element its string-value (`string()`). It's *"the concatenation of the string-values of all its descendant text nodes"*, [as E. Lenz puts it](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell/):

```
$ xidel -s https://www.iana.org/domains/arpa -e '
  //table[@id="arpa-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2] ! (position(),.)
'
#or
$ xidel -s https://www.iana.org/domains/arpa -e '
  //table[@id="arpa-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/string() ! (position(),.)
'
1
Reserved exclusively to support operationally-critical infrastructural identifier spaces as advised by the Internet Architecture Board

                RFC 3172
```

As you can see, 1 item/node.
That's why `normalize-space(td[2])` returns `Reserved exclusively [...] RFC 3172`.

With `text()` on the other hand you'll get the node/element its direct text-nodes:

```
$ xidel -s https://www.iana.org/domains/arpa -e '
  //table[@id="arpa-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text() ! (position(),.)
'
1
Reserved exclusively to support operationally-critical infrastructural identifier spaces as advised by the Internet Architecture Board
2



3
```

Or all of its descendant text-nodes:

```
$ xidel -s https://www.iana.org/domains/arpa -e '
  //table[@id="arpa-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]//text() ! (position(),.)
'
1
Reserved exclusively to support operationally-critical infrastructural identifier spaces as advised by the Internet Architecture Board
2



3
RFC 3172
4
```

As you can see, 3 and 4 different items/nodes.

To get the 1<sup>st</sup> text-node, simply `td[2]/text()[1]` would do, but `normalize-space(td[2]/text())` and even `normalize-space(td[2]//text())` would work too.